# Got an error when trying to upload apk to google play

Tags: android, upload, google-play, apk

Did anyone encountered this problem: "ERROR getting 'android:name' attribute: attribute is not a string value"? I got it when I tried to upload an apk to google play, and I dont imagine what could be a problem in my apk, cause it works perfectly. Is it a bug?

Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="app.com.discountscatcher"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="19"
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_actionbar_title"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver
        android:name="com.discountscatcher.util.NotifyDeleteReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="@string/intent_filter_deleteintent" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.discountscatcher.main.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.discountscatcher.main.PromoListActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="com.discountscatcher.util.PointService" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.discountscatcher.main.AboutActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.discountscatcher.main.PromoActivityDetails"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.discountscatcher.util.TEST_SERVICE_EMULATING" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.discountscatcher.main.FullScreenImageActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="3265130" />

    <activity android:name="com.discountscatcher.main.DiscountsCatcherActivity" >
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.discountscatcher.util.RebootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: I things there is a problem in xml, specially in values folder.So check there.

Comment: please look for yours package at manifes and at activity

Comment: You need to give app name as a string in string.xml file which is located in res-->values-->string.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Define `package="app.com.discountscatcher"`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="app.com.discountscatcher" // Your application Package
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

But you are using **com.discountscatcher.main.MainActivity**

```
<activity
        android:name="com.discountscatcher.main.MainActivity" // Different Package name
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Try change it to `"app.com.discountscatcher"`

Like `app.com.discountscatcher.MainActivity`

Comment: Thx man, but then why it doesn't throw me any error when i've launch an app and use it?

Comment: @whizzzkey The package name identified in the AndroidManifest.xml is the unique indetifier for the application. so need to follow these convension..

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your package name. Please do this, I have corrected this. Please verify you package name two times. Package name needs to be same always every place in your app.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="app.com.discountscatcher"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="19"
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_actionbar_title"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver
        android:name=".util.NotifyDeleteReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="@string/intent_filter_deleteintent" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".main.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".main.PromoListActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".util.PointService" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".main.AboutActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".main.PromoActivityDetails"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".util.TEST_SERVICE_EMULATING" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".main.FullScreenImageActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="3265130" />

    <activity android:name=".main.DiscountsCatcherActivity" >
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".util.RebootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```